# How can i create a column from 2 related columns of lists in python?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

| sampleID | testnames | results |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23939332 | [32131,34343,35566] | [NEGATIVE,0.234,3.331] |
| 32332323 | [34343,96958,39550,88088] | [0,312,0.008,0.1,0.2] |

The table above is what I have, and the one below is what I want to achieve:

| sampleID | 32131 | 34343 | 39550 | 88088 | 96985 | 35566 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23939332 | NEGATIVE | 0.234 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 3.331 |
| 32332323 | NaN | 0,312 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.008 | NaN |

So I need to create columns of unique values from the `testnames` column and fill the cells with the corresponding values from the `results` column.

Considering this is as a sample from a very large dataset (table).

Comment: What is the number of different test names? Depending on this, the shape you asked for might be very large and very sparse. So large that before having speed issues to build it, you will get a `ValueError: Unstacked DataFrame is too big, causing int32 overflow`.

Comment: 1248 unique testnames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a commented solution:

```py
(df.set_index(['sampleID'])  # keep sampleID out of the expansion
   .apply(pd.Series.explode) # expand testnames and results
   .reset_index()            # reset the index
   .groupby(['sampleID', 'testnames']) # 
   .first()                            # set the expected shape
   .unstack())                         #
```

It gives the result you expected, though with a different column order:

```
            results                                 
testnames     32131  34343  35566 39550 88088  96958
sampleID                                            
23939332   NEGATIVE  0.234  3.331   NaN   NaN    NaN
32332323        NaN  0.312    NaN   0.1   0.2  0.008
```

Let's see how it does on generated data:

```py
def build_df(n_samples, n_tests_per_sample, n_test_types):
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['sampleID', 'testnames', 'results'])
    test_types = np.random.choice(range(0,100000), size=n_test_types, replace=False)
    for i in range(n_samples):
        testnames = list(np.random.choice(test_types,size=n_tests_per_sample))
        results = list(np.random.random(size=n_tests_per_sample))
        df = df.append({'sampleID': i, 'testnames':testnames, 'results':results}, ignore_index=True)
    return df

def reshape(df):
    df2 = (df.set_index(['sampleID'])  # keep the sampleID out of the expansion
             .apply(pd.Series.explode) # expand testnames and results
             .reset_index()            # reset the index
             .groupby(['sampleID', 'testnames']) # 
             .first()                            # set the expected shape
             .unstack())   
    return df2

%time df = build_df(60000, 10, 100)
# Wall time: 9min 48s (yes, it was ugly)

%time df2 = reshape(df)
# Wall time: 1.01 s
```

`reshape()` breaks when `n_test_types` becomes too large, with `ValueError: Unstacked DataFrame is too big, causing int32 overflow`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but a data with 60.000+ rows would take forever to .explode. I don't seem to have a solution with this.

Comment: Tested with several tens of thousands of rows with 10 random testnames each: it is quite efficient, but it breaks by the size of the resulting huge and mainly empty DataFrame before taking a long time. See my comment on your question to make it more precise.

Comment: So the problem was that my data had lots of faulty lists, sizes didnt match. thank you for your solution sir.